# Displaying new label on a list item from the database

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Please i have this list of data i want to display from the database but i want to give a label of new to a new data and nothing to an old data how do i achieve this in laravel

**FOR EXAMPLE**

[image: db item list sample]

**THE CODE**

```
                    <!-- desktop view -->
                    <div class="large-2 columns show-for-large-only">
                        <span class="new-user-list-label text-center montserrat-font white-text small-text-13">New</span>
                        @if ($user->created_at == Carbon::now())

                        @elseif ($user->updated_at == Carbon::now())
                            <span class="new-user-list-label text-center montserrat-font white-text small-text-13">New</span>
                        @endif
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x large-centered">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x tq-dark-blue-color"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input name="" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-size-20">
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-10 columns show-for-large-only">
                        <ul class="no-bullet">
                            <li><h6 class="text-left montserrat-font small-text-15 capitalize"><b>USERNAME | </b> {{ $user->name }}</h6></li>
                            <li><h6 class="text-left montserrat-font small-text-15 lowercase"><b class="uppercase">EMAIL | </b> {{ $user->email }}</h6></li>
                            <li><h6 class="text-left montserrat-font small-text-15"><b>REGISTERED | </b> {{ Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($user->created_at))->diffForHumans() }}</h6></li>
                            <li><h6 class="text-left montserrat-font small-text-15"><b>ATTIRES MADE | </b> Attires made</h6></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><h6 class="text-left montserrat-font footer-links small-text-15">More info...</h6></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /end desktop view -->
```

Comment: We can't help without you showing your code

Comment: @f_anto ooh am sorry right on it.

Comment: What needs changing? Can you please explain your problem in more detail? It would be useful to see your controller, your model, and possibly your route

Comment: Well i have a list of items that i want to show in the views but on each of the item that is a new item (for example a new registered user) The new label with pink should indicate as a new user while for others nothing will show, i have not written any controller or db for it, just the listed item and the image, i need support on implementing this @brianlmerritt

Comment: Yes, so can you show the relevant parts of your model and controller? No one is going to write this for you from scratch - please show how far you have got thanks!